# Freeform loses its values if an error occurs when not using the standard {freeform:field:short_name}

Tags: solspace-freeform

due to the nature of my project, I cannot use the standard freeform syntax:

```
    {freeform:field:short_name}
```

I instead have to use the following syntax:

```
    <div class="ui left aligned icon input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Vor- Nachname" id="short_name" value="" name="short_name" required />   
        <i class="user icon"></i>
        <div class="ui corner label"><i class="asterisk icon"></i></div>
    </div>
```

It all works great - but If one omits something that triggers an error, the fields that were already filled in are blank.

I am looking to populate the value="" parameter with the things one entered before the error occurred.

e.g. value="{..._short_name}

is this possible?

btw: values are stored if you use the {freeform:field:short_name} syntax.

cheers
stefan

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around I found an undocumented feature:

you can add almost all attributes within the standard field syntax. 
so this works:

```
    <label for="name">My Field Label</label>
    <div class="ui left aligned icon input">
        {freeform:field:my_field attr:placeholder="My Field Label" attr:id="my_field" attr:required="required"}
        <i class="user icon"></i>
        <div class="ui corner label"><i class="asterisk icon"></i></div>
    </div>
```

the attr:placeholder, attr:required were not documented, but work like they should! 
great!

Comment: Anything you use with attr:attribute_name="attribute_value" is usually passed directly to the field as an attribute unless otherwise mentioned in the docs: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#text_attr_name