# Freeform Pro - display reqired fields

Tags: solspace-freeform

In Freeform I use the loop to display all my fields:

```
{freeform:all_form_fields}
    <dt>
        <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <!-- place holder for ajax errors-->
        <div class="error_message"></div>
        {freeform:field_output}
    </dd>
{/freeform:all_form_fields}
```

how can I display an asterix beside fields which are required?
Form called and required fields displayed like:

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form:id="ajax_form"
    form:class="form-horizontal"
    form_name="enq_form"
    required="business_name|business_category|contact_person|email_address"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hard-coded the required fields in the template by including them in the template tag, so why not hard code it in your loop?

```
<label>
    {freeform:field_label}
    {if freeform:field_name == "business_name" 
        || freeform:field_name == "business_category"
        || freeform:field_name == "contact_person" 
        || freeform:field_name == "email_address"}
        <span class="required">*</span>
    {/if}
</label>
```

I didn't say it was a great solution! In the docs there's no mention of freeform:field_required variable :(

I'd strongly recommend you use the [Composer](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/composer) though - especially as you have the Pro version. It is really great, and you can create a template that is fully flexible for any type of form your editor/admin wants to create. And it has a variable to detect if a field is required. So nothing is hard coded in the template!  [See an example here](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/composer/#examples), or you want more example code, raise another question.

Comment: I already had the form done in Composer but changed to the Form and Ajax submission as I wanted the form to retain the values when the user made an error. In composer when there was an error the form was blanked.

Comment: Thought you went down the Ajax route to solve that?: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/35474/freeform-pro-composer-retain-field-values-on-error - You an still use Ajax with Composer.

Comment: Ah I did - but used the example in the docs on their website which used the standard form - never thought of the Ajax with Composer - that would have been the best solution!